# Why don't we require a lazy-init getter to be synchronized (the holder idiom)?

Tags: java, multithreading, lazy-initialization

I'm reading J. Bloch's effective Java and now I'm at the section about lazy-initialization. Consider the following class:

```
public class LazyInit{

    public static getObject(){  //Not synchronized
        return Holder.o;
    }

    private static Object createObject(){
        System.out.println("Creating started");
        return new Object();
    }

    private static class Holder{
        private static Object o = createObject();
    }
}
```

J. Bloch said about this idiom:

> The beauty of this idiom is that the  getField  method ***is not***
>   ***synchronized*** and performs only a field access, so lazy
>   initialization adds practically nothing to the cost of access.

I don't understand why it is safe through. What if during the initialization of the field another thread try to access the field concurrently? The object is not created by the time the thread need it. So, what is going to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach is based on initialization principles of JVM.

Instance of `Object` will be created only after loading of `Holder` class. Loading of `Holder` class will be performed by classloader during the first reference to field `o` in your application (here it is `getObject` method). Classloading is non-cuncurrent, so this pattern guarantees that:

1. `Object` instance will be created on demand (lazy initialization).
2. Creation of `Object` will be thread-safe.

Taken from [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom):

> Since the class initialization phase is guaranteed by the JLS to be serial, i.e., non-concurrent, no further synchronization is required in the static getInstance method during loading and initialization.

---

### Update from comments:

@St.Antario found [formal JLS explanation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2) for this feature:

> The procedure for initializing C is then as follows: Synchronize on the initialization lock, LC, for C. This involves waiting until the current thread can acquire LC.

Comment: Not clear. So what happend if during the class intialization by one thread another one will try to access its field. Will it be locked till the initialization finished?

Comment: @St.Antario, that's the trick. Object instance will be created during initialization of Holder class and Holder class is initialized non-concurrently, that means that second thread will wait until Holder class is initialized as well as first thread.

Comment: Actually, got it. Here is some [formal jls explanation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2) I found:  __The procedure for initializing C is then as follows: Synchronize on the initialization lock, LC, for C. This involves waiting until the current thread can acquire LC.__ It might be useful for someone if you added some formal refrences to your answer.

Comment: Since class initialization is non-concurrent, this could also be an antipattern when initialization expensive and could be done in parallel.